# Select row in SQL using GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server

When creating the table I used

```
[Key] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
```

I'm trying to use the following to select, I gave up on doing it in C# for now and am entering the query in MyLittleAdmin (the SQL database manager my hosting provider is using)

```
SELECT * 
FROM GameList 
WHERE Key = '9abc2cdc-1919-e611-80d3-008cfa5ae917'
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line number 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.

I know I have the right GUID, using `SELECT * FROM GameList` returns the data and I have copied and pasted from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Key` is a keyword and must be surroundted by string identifiers if you want to use it as a column name (like it is in the column definition):

```
SELECT * 
FROM GameList  
WHERE [Key] = '9abc2cdc-1919-e611-80d3-008cfa5ae917'
```